# NDK build error (error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

#### File *Application.mk*

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := all
```

#### File *Android.mk*

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libz
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/libz.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include/
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/libssl.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcrypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/libcrypto.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libjson-c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/libjson-c.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcurl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/include/libcurlall/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcurl.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := curl-ndk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../cpp/curl-http.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcurl libssl libcrypto libz libjson-c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -llog -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Clean the project. I'm trying to cross compile NDK, but then it shows the error given below:

```
/Volumes/Work/Android/Projects/app/src/main/jni/../prebuild/libz.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/Volumes/Work/Android/Projects/app/src/main/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libcurl-ndk.so] Error 1
```

It's working fine on 32 bits, but on 64 bit it shows an error.

Comment: do you replace your  prebuilt libraries with the 64 bit versions before build?

Answer (score 0):

You're using one prebuilt for all ABIs. You need one prebuilt for each ABI you target. The typical way to write a prebuilt module is like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libz
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libz.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include/
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Then you can have prebuild/armeabi-v7a/libz.a, prebuild/arm64-v8a/libz.a, etc. Disable ABIs you don't want to build for (or don't have prebuilts for) using `APP_ABI` in your Application.mk.